# Codewars: Which are In? lexicographical order (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, sorting, lexicographic-ordering

I am currently trying to solve below question in Codewars in javascript.
Below is the question:

"Given two arrays of strings a1 and a2 return a sorted array r in lexicographical order of the strings of a1 which are substrings of strings of a2."

Below is the code that I wrote for this question:

```
function inArray(array1,array2){
  var result = [];
  var newResult = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
      if(array2[i].includes(array1[j])) {
        result.push(array1[j])
      }
    }
  }

  for(var k = 0; k < result.length; k++) {
    if(result[k] !== result[k+1]) {
      newResult.push(result[k]);
    }
  }

  return newResult.sort();
}
```

Here are the example tests that I have to pass:

```
a2 = ["lively", "alive", "harp", "sharp", "armstrong"]
a1 = ["xyz", "live", "strong"]
Test.assertSimilar(inArray(a1, a2), ["live", "strong"])
a1 = ["live", "strong", "arp"]
Test.assertSimilar(inArray(a1, a2), ["arp", "live", "strong"])
a1 = ["tarp", "mice", "bull"]
Test.assertSimilar(inArray(a1, a2), [])
```

My code seem to pass all the example tests, but I am not able to get pass all the specs. It says I am failing 5 specs out of the 10 specs.
I don't know why I am failing those specs.
Is there a problem with my code or is there any way I can make my code better?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to change the for loops (starting with `array1`, instead of `array2`) and use a label for skipping the inner loop if the item is found.

With this method, you do not need to filter the result for duplicates.

```js
function inArray(array1, array2) {
    var i, j, result = [];

    outer: for (j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
            if (array2[i].includes(array1[j])) {
                result.push(array1[j]);
                continue outer;
            }
        }
    }
    return result.sort();
}

var Test = {
    assertSimilar: function (a, b) {
        console.log('result', a);
        console.log('given', b);
    }
};

a2 = ["lively", "alive", "harp", "sharp", "armstrong"];
a1 = ["xyz", "live", "strong"];
Test.assertSimilar(inArray(a1, a2), ["live", "strong"]);
a1 = ["live", "strong", "arp"];
Test.assertSimilar(inArray(a1, a2), ["arp", "live", "strong"]);
a1 = ["tarp", "mice", "bull"];
Test.assertSimilar(inArray(a1, a2), []);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that you should be asking for a solution to a kata on Stack Overflow but since you are almost there here are my ideas.

Firstly, when not sure why failing final tests use console.log() and look at the values that are being tested and possibly even the expected results (depends on the way the kata is written).

Secondly, your solution does not work because you are including the doubles /duplicates in your final answer.

I am currently using sets to get rid of duplicates in JS code. Sets include only unique values and are really cool. If you add the following three of lines instead of current return in your code it should pass all the tests:

```
var setOfRes = new Set(newResult.sort());
var array = Array.from(setOfRes);
return array;
```

Yes, I am converting from an Array to a Set to get rid of duplicates and then back into an Array. It can be done in many other ways but Sets are a great tool so here is my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
function inArray(arrA, arrB){
  let arr = arrB.join(" ")
  return arrA.filter(item => arr.search(item) !== -1 && item !== undefined ).sort()

}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your solution

Comment: let arr = arrB.join(" ") // converts their arrB to a string separated by "  "  then i filter the arrA which contains the words to look for. if a string or item inside arrA is also inside the (arr string separated by "  ")  and item is not undefined then add it to the new list created by the filter method.

Comment: You can edit your answer. Your solution fails, if search contains `" "`. Ex: `["a  b","c d"] ["b c"]` `"b c"` false positive.

Comment: Good catch! I believe I need to change ```javascript arrB.join(" ")``` to  ```javascript  arrB.join("")```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .sort()

```
function inArray(array1,array2){
  var x;
  var y;
  var r = [];
  for (x = 0; x < array1.length; x++) { 
    for (y = 0; y < array2.length; y++) {
      if(array2[y].includes(array1[x]) === true){
          r.push(array1[x]);
      }else{

      }
    }
  }
  r = [...new Set(r)];
  return r.sort();
}
```